# Strange artifact in writing to serial while executing loop

Tags: serial, rgb-led, led-strip, functions

Hope you can see this.

https://gist.github.com/DevilWAH/60ad144d2858f53845ac2e80f84bb070

The main file in this is "morse-led-rfid" which is taking reading data of an RFID tag and then displaying the text as Morse code on to a APA102 / Dotstar LED strip.

The issue is when the function updatestrip(tempbuffer[i]); is called.

```
Serial.println(F("\n**Start Reading**\n"));

  for (uint8_t i = 1; i < 15; i++)
  {
   if (i != 3 && i!= 7 && i != 11 && i != 15 ) // Skip the non data blocks 
    {
     readblock (i, key);
       for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
         {
      updatestrip(tempbuffer[i]);
      Serial.write(tempbuffer[i]);
        }
    }
  }
```

This is what I am calling to scroll the LED strip and write the letter in morse. if in the code snip it above i comment out "updatestrip...." then i get the txt from the RFID tag printer to serial as i would expect.

as a soon as i un comment it, the strip displays the morse code but the serial output gets garbled, it misses letters, prints reversed "?'s" and repeats its self?

Good output = "My Bunny is the best"
Bad output = "?Bunny is the ?t" (question marks reversed)

Further investigation i found if i leave it uncommented but go all the way to the bottom of the "more-strip" sheet and comment out the "else statement in the shiftLED function" the serial again displays correctly, but of course the led don't :)

```
void shiftLED() // shift all LED up 1 
  {
    for(uint16_t i = ledCount; i > 0; i--)
    {


      if ((colors[i - 1].red == 0 ) && (colors[i - 1].green == 0 ))
       {
          colors[i] = cblack;
        }
      else if (i > 19 && i < 40)
      {
        colors[i] = cred;
      }  
     // else 
     // {
     //   colors[i] = cgreen;
     // }
     // }


 }
```

Can any one suggest why the else statement a few function down is affecting the "serial.write(tempbuffer[i])" in the main loop?

Comment: Using an `i` loop inside an `i` loop is very bad practice. Never nest the same variable like that - it makes it impossible to know what you intend.

Comment: Hi, I did actuality think that, and went though and changed this. I have to admit to being a very hacky programmer (not sure i can even call my self that, it an insult to the real ones). Will add to list of things not to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `colors` is declared as

```
rgb_color colors[ledCount];
```

This means that the very first iteration of this cycle in `shiftLED`

```
for (uint16_t i = ledCount; i > 0; i--)
{
  // access colors[i]
}
```

will access `ledCount[ledCount]` which is obviously out of bounds (and will actually *write* into that location!). The behavior is undefined after that.

Using unsigned types for "backward" array iteration requires a bit of skill. The common idioms are

```
for (uint16_t i = ledCount; i > 0;)
{
  --i; // do this ASAP

  // access colors[i]
}
```

or

```
for (uint16_t i = ledCount; i-- > 0;)
{
  // access colors[i]
}
```

or

```
// Careful: this technique is not usable with unsigned types 
// narrower than `unsigned int`
for (uint16_t i = ledCount - 1; i != -1; --i)
{
  // access colors[i]
}
```

This is assuming that you want to iterate over the whole array: from `[ledCount - 1]` all the way back to `[0]`.

But if you intended to iterate back to `[1]` and stop short of `[0]` (which is apparently the case), then a simple fix for your cycle would be

```
for (uint16_t i = ledCount - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
  // access colors[i]
}
```

I.e. simply start from `ledCount - 1`, not from `ledCount`.

Comment: OH! correct me is I am wrong but you mean when LEDCount = 60 the valid array values are 0 though 59? so accessing access colors[i] when i = LEDCount means i am writing to array position 60 not 59! A kind of buffer over flow?

Comment: And you got me to go look up more about signed and unsigned. When back at home tonight i will try out your suggestions, thanks for the help.

Comment: @DevilWAH Yes, if `LEDCount` is `60`, then the valid indexes for `colors` array are from `0` to `59`. Index `60` is out of bounds.

Comment: Just to confirm that sorted it out :) thank you for taking the time out to help and explain.